# Custom WordPress search query ignoring posts_per_page on pre_get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, algolia

I've been working with this function and for some reason, I cannot seem to figure out the issue here.

I have a function that I want to affect the search results to change the number of `posts_per_page` of the query to be unlimited.

For whatever reason, `$query->set('posts_per_page', -1)` and `$query->set('post__in', $post__in)` appear to do nothing while `$query->set('tax_query', $tax_query)` *does* work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

```
    function fp_search_query_mod( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) :

        $cats = ( isset($_GET['cats'] ) ? $_GET['cats'] : null );

        $post__in = array();

        if ( !empty( $cats ) ) :

            $cats = explode( ',', $cats );

            $tax_query = array(

                'relation'  => 'AND',

                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'simple', 'variable' ) 
                ),

                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'id',
                    'terms'    => $cats,
                )

            );

            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

            if ( in_array( 'favs', $cats ) ) :

                $fp_favs = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'fp_favs', true );

                if ( !empty( $fp_favs ) ) {

                    $post__in = $fp_favs;

                }

            endif;

            if ( in_array( 'purchases', $cats ) ) :

                // $purchased = get_customer_purchased_products();
                $purchased = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'fp_purchases', true );

                if ( !empty( $post__in ) ) {

                    $post__in = array_merge( $post__in, $purchased );

                    $post__in = array_unique( $post__in );

                } else {

                    $post__in = $purchased;

                }

            endif;

        endif;

        if ( !empty( $post__in ) ) :

            $query->set( 'post__in', $post__in );

        endif;

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );

    endif;

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fp_search_query_mod', 2 );
```

Here's the page on which the resuls are displayed: https://filmpacdev.wpengine.com/?s=beaches&post_type=product

Comment: Could it be that there is another plugin filtering into `pre_get_posts`? You could change your prio from 2 to 999 or something, just to eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Also, you can dump, after the query has run, your global `$wp_query` object, to see what parameters have been set.

Comment: Sure thing—it's pretty massive, so I output it, here: http://rightly.work/9200b0 Also, I added 999 to the priority and it just removed the pagination of the page—so there is definitely something weird happening. I think it may have to do with Algolia's results.

Comment: I just did a quick check and `posts_per_page` should be in `$wp_query->query_vars`. If it's not, something is probably overwriting the main query.

Comment: Have you tried removing the priority of `2` that you set, or changing it to 1?